# Display huge tiled image on android phone

Tags: android, maps, tiles

I have a very large image (a map) that I need to display. I already have the image in "tiled" format - 256x256 pieces.
Also I got tiles for several "zoom" levels.

At the moment the issue is to display the deepest zoom level, where you'd have really a lot of tiles.
For example, a medium sized map will contain 4 rows and 26 columns of tiles for deep level.

I tried approaching the problem using a 2 dimensional scroll view and image views inside it - 1 per tile.
The problems is that it crashes. When I try displaying 4 rows and 20 columns it doesn't crash, obviously it's a memory issue.

So the question here - how to display all that, taking into account limited phone RAM.
I do understand there should be a way to dealocate memory for images that are out of sight, and only display those which are currently in visible area of the scroll view, but I don't know how to do that.

Would be happy to hear any clues or maybe there's alternative approach to these things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might better use the grid view instead of arrays of scroll view (but I am not sure if it support side/updown scroll at the same time.

And then in your adapter, override the `getView` method. There you can control the recycling of your images.

The project I am doing also have issues with image and RAM, what I am basically doing is like:

```
image.recycle();
System.gc();
```

I tried doing the above stuff like 50fps with the image is like 800x400x32bit and still not running into out of memory issue. But if I take away the System.gc(), it crash immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up using a custom view which can be scrollable vertically/horizontally and drawing directly to the canvas in onDraw method, and keeping a cached copy of tiles nearby, seems to do most of the things i need, needs some further caching tweaking, but it's a good start.